# Connecting information entropy to the prime number theorem for compression of numbers?

Tags: probability, soft-question, prime-numbers, computer-science, information-theory

1. Prime number theorem states how often primes occur (approx. how densely they are distributed).
2. The Shannon theorem of information entropy gives us a lower bound of how much data is at least required to store some information.
3. Prime factorization theorem allows us to uniquely map each positive integer number to a set of prime exponents.

Can these things be combined somehow to create a number system which is on average more efficient, than say for example the binary number system?

Comment: Define "more efficient".

Comment: @GerryMyerson : require less bits on average to store a number.

Comment: How many bits does the binary number system require on average to store a number?

Comment: @GerryMyerson if we just use first or second complements it's $\lceil\log_2(N)\rceil$ bits where $N$ is the number of maximal size we want to be able to represent.

Comment: Well, if you want to represent all the numbers (positive integers) up to $N$, then there is only one that you can represent with one bit, two that you can represent with two bits, four that you can represent with three bits, and so on. That tells you that you can't do any better, on average, than the binary number system, no?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes if there is uniform distribution among the numbers and we don't want to encode the prime factors to avoid having to factor each number. For example division and multiplication becomes much easier in a prime number encoding.

Comment: OK, you're introducing a couple of new concepts into the discussion. One, if you have a known distribution on the numbers then you want to do a Huffman encoding, q.v. Two, if you don't want to just store the numbers, but you want to do arithmetic on them, then sure representing by prime decomposition beats binary for multiplication, but it loses bigtime for addition and subtraction. You really have to decide what it is you want to do, before you can ask a sensible question.

Comment: Any thoughts, mathreadler?

Comment: Lots of thoughts, always. But none that seems useful right now.